# just started learning Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I don't know why this does not work. I get an error saying "Error: 1 is not a function[(anon)]"

```
(define (mem lst ele)
  (cond ;if the list is empty return false
    ((null? lst) #f)
    ;if the first element is equal to the given element return true
    ;otherwise call the function with rest of the list
    (else (if (= ele (car lst)) 
              #t 
              (mem (cdr lst) ele)))))

(mem ’(1) ’(1 4 -2))
```

Comment: The sample input which you have added to your question does not cause the error that you report. That error would be caused by something other than incorrect single quotes. Have you changed the input since you wrote the question? Are you using Scheme? Racket? A student language? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me; how are you calling `mem`? I am guessing that you did something like: `(mem (1 2 3 4) 1)`. Procedure calls *always* evaluate their arguments in Scheme, so in the procedure call `(mem (1 2 3 4) 1)` the expression `(1 2 3 4)` is evaluated; but lists are evaluated as if the first member is a procedure, so `1` is treated as a function; it is not, and this raises an exception.

You could quote the list: `(mem (quote (1 2 3 4)) 1)`, or you can use the shorthand `(mem '(1 2 3 4) 1)`. `quote` is a special form that does not evaluate its argument; instead it just returns whatever datum it is given. You can try this out at the REPL:

```
> (+ 1 2)
3
> (quote (+ 1 2))
(+ 1 2)
> '(+ 1 2)
(+ 1 2)
```

Here the naked expression `(+ 1 2)` evaluates to `3`, but the quoted expressions just return the expressions given to `quote`. That is, `(quote (+ 1 2))` evaluates to the expression `(+ 1 2)`, not to the result of evaluating the expression `(+ 1 2)`. In the case of `(1 2 3 4)`:

```
> (quote (1 2 3 4))
(1 2 3 4)
> '(1 2 3 4)
(1 2 3 4)
> (1 2 3 4)

Exception: attempt to apply non-procedure 1
Type (debug) to enter the debugger.
```

The procedure call `(mem '(1 2 3 4) 1)` would evaluate the expression `'(1 2 3 4)` before passing that value to `mem`. Since the expression `'(1 2 3 4)` evaluates to a *list*, that list is the value which is passed to `mem`. This differs from the erroneous call `(mem (1 2 3 4) 1)`, which attempts to evaluate the expression `(1 2 3 4)` by calling the (nonexistent) procedure `1` with the arguments `2`, `3`, and `4`.

You could also use `list` to create the input: `(mem (list 1 2 3 4) 1)`. `list` is also a procedure, and so it evaluates its arguments. Here the call to `mem` would evaluate the expression `(list 1 2 3 4)`, and since `list` is a procedure the call to `list` would evaluate the arguments `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`. Numbers are self-evaluating in Scheme, so the call to `list` would return a list `(1 2 3 4)`; this *list* is the value passed to `mem`, which has now evaluated its argument `(list 1 2 3 4)`.

### Some Comments on the Posted Code

The `cond` form can take multiple conditional clauses, and there is no reason to use `if` here. Instead, you can do:

```scheme
(define (mem lst ele)
  (cond
   ((null? lst) #f)
   ((= ele (car lst)) #t)
   (else
    (mem (cdr lst) ele))))
```

The `=` predicate only works for numbers; to handle more general inputs you might choose `equal?`:

```scheme
(define (mem lst ele)
  (cond
   ((null? lst) #f)
   ((equal? ele (car lst)) #t)
   (else
    (mem (cdr lst) ele))))
```

Now you can work with, e.g., lists of symbols, or lists of lists:

```scheme
> (mem '(a b c d) 'c)
#t
> (mem '(a b c d) 'e)
#f
> (mem '(1 (2 3) 4) '(2 3))
#t
> (mem '(1 (2 (3 4)) 5) '(2 (3 4)))
#t
> (mem '(1 (2 3) 4) 3)  ;; does not descend into nested lists
#f
```

Note that changing the equality predicate to `equal?` will allow lists to be searched for at the top level of the input list, but no deeper. The list `(2 (3 4))` can be found in the list `(1 (2 (3 4)) 5)` because it is at the top level of the list, i.e., `(2 (3 4))` is an element of the list `(1 (2 (3 4)) 5)`. But, `(3 4)` is *not* an element of the top level list, so the current `mem` procedure can't find it here. Another definition for `mem` would be needed to search within nested lists.

Comment: I'm calling it like this ```(mem ’(1) ’(1 4 -2))```

Comment: @student -- that can't be. First, you have the wrong quotes in `(mem ’(1) ’(1 4 -2))`, so Racket (or Scheme) thinks that these quotes start identifiers, and responds with: `; ’: undefined;`. Second, even with the quotes fixed (you need single quotes) a different error message is produced: `;   expected: number?;   given: '(1 4 -2)`. This is because this call does not match the signature. You must have done something else to get the error `Error: 1 is not a function`, although Racket gives a slightly different message; are you using a student language?

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your example that you are looking for the list `'(1 4 -2)` in the list `'(1)`, which should evaluate to `#f`. However your implementation expects all elements to be numbers since you compare with `=` which is a number only comparison procedure. If you want to compare any type you should use `equal?` which compares two objects of any type and supports comparing structures.

Answer (score -1):

You were using an [acute-accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent) instead of a single-quote for your literals.

```
#lang racket

(define (mem ele lst)  ;;  easier to read with one element -then- list
                       ;;  ..plus that's how you wrote your call to it,
                       ;;  so this arg-order makes more sense here.

  (cond  ;;  cond doesn't need "else"

    ((null? lst) #f)

    ((if (= ele (car lst)) #t
         (mem ele (cdr lst))))  ;; element, then list now
  )
)

(mem 1 '(1 4 -2))
;;  don't know why element needed to be wrapped in a '(1) literal list container
;;  also literals require single-quote ' character, not the ’ acute-accent
```

https://docs.racket-lang.org/racket-cheat/index.html

Comment: None of the OP's claimed input `(mem ’(1) ’(1 4 -2))` (which was not included in the question until after I wrote my answer) matches OP's claimed error message: `"Error: 1 is not a function[(anon)]"`; acute accent would not raise a "1 is not a function" error.

Comment: I was running into the same issue as you pointed out **the error doesn't match what's given** - that's not on me.  So I responded with what I saw.  Maybe he figures it out, maybe it helps somebody else down the line;  because that is an important point, mixing backticks / accents / quotes in Lisp can wreck a script.